# Hide UIButton title

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, title

I have several UIButtons in a scrollview which I use in order to pass certain information.  The information is saved in the title of each uibutton and when the button is clicked, it passes its title into the function.

All I want to do is hide the title of the button so you can not see the button. I have them overlaid over images which I use to show buttons. I have the text set to transparent but it still turns white when it is being clicked.

If you include code in your explanation, please explain where it should go.

Comment: Do you mean like `myButton.hidden = YES;` ?

Comment: if that still makes the button clickable, then yes, where would i put that though?  I have several buttons in the view

Comment: You are doing this wrong. First, why don't you store a variable with the name instead of using the title? Second, invisible buttons is a TERRIBLE idea, your app might even get rejected. Third, if you are using an image to show the buttons, why don't set that image to the button?. Fourth, how do you want us to explain where the code should go if you didn't provide any code?

Answer (score 32):

After IOS7, If you want to just hide the title on titleLabel of a button you can do as follow. This way the title is still there it just makes it invisible. if you do NSLog("%@",button.currentTitle) you will see the title in terminal. Hope this helps.

```
[button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
```

Comment: yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.clearColor(), forState: .Normal)

Comment: This is the only valid solution, this way you can still have your title (for different states) and you don't need to retain `titleLabel` or any other variables

Answer (score 15):

I found only one correct working way:

```
//hide
yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.clearColor(), forState: .Normal)

//show (put your color)
yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 14):

using `button.titleLabel.hidden = YES` will not work (at least on on iOS 7).

I ended up using:

```
// remove the button since hiding it doesn't work
[button.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];
// put back when you're done
[button addSubview:button.titleLabel];
```

Comment: I do not understand this syntax you are using, but `titleLabel?.removeFromSuperview()` works for me, because I never want to use the titleLabel. Out of sight, out of mind.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the label inside the button:

```
button.titleLabel.hidden=YES;
```

or set the button's title to @"" and save the value somewhere else when you want to retrieve it.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work with iOS7. Depending on when in the view cycle you use it.

Answer (score 5):

I create a subclass of UIButton and override `layoutSubviews` method. Hiding titleLabel in `layoutSubviews` method works.

```
public class LoadingButton: UIButton {
    public var isTitleHidden: Bool = false {
        didSet {
           titleLabel?.isHidden = isTitleHidden
        }
    }
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.isHidden = isTitleHidden
    }
}
```

if wanna hide titleLabel, just set `isTitleHidden = true`

Comment: Your answer is the best! Thx

Answer (score 3):

I could not remove the title from the `titleLabel` nor the whole view as I needed it for constraints.

I ended up using

```
isEnabled = false
titleLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
setTitleColor(.clear, for: .disabled)
```

to hide the title and

```
isEnabled = true
titleLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
setTitleColor(titleColor(for: .normal), for: .disabled)
```

to show it again

Comment: Changing the opacity did the trick. Setting the title to `nil` might also change the button size, a problem which this solution doesn't suffer from.

Answer (score 3):

To hide a title temporary just setTitle to empty string

```
setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

the button title label will be **hidden** but the **title will still in the titleLabel**, you can return it back using

```
setTitle(titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporary hide the title, while you disabling the button, use:

```
setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
setTitle("", for: .disabled)
```

Then, `button.isEnabled = false`, when you want to hide the title.

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem with title, because used an attributed title and nothing above helped. Then i found a workaround:

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: shouldHide ? 1000 : 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

However it has some disadvantages, but fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution, which allows you to set title label text and use it with button image without showing it and not moving button image to the left.

```
- (void)hideButtonLabel:(UIButton*)buttonInp {

    buttonInp.titleLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
    uttonInp.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:0.0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide `UIButton` `titleLabel` using `.hidden` property. Instead you can do this.

To Hide:

```
[self.yourButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To Show:

```
[self.yourButton setTitle:@"Your Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift-

You don't need to hide nor need to make the opacity to 0.0. Swift gave you a simpler way.
Just set the title as nil. In fact, I got the idea from the documentation.

Command click on the `setTitle(_:for:)` method and you will see-

```
open func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControl.State) // default is nil. title is assumed to be single line
```

So, I just set it to nil.

```
setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 to hide button label:

```
myButton.titleLabel?.isHidden = true
```

Here myButton is a @IBOutlet of the button.